# Why is the Son on the Star Wars Rebels poster?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-rebels

Why is the Son from the Mortis trilogy on the Star Wars Rebels poster? Isn't he dead?

[image]

Comment: @Valorum Why did you replace the poster by one that doesn't contain the character the question is about? Did the site you embedded it from change it since you edited in?

Comment: @CodesInChaos - Yes, they replaced it with a russian version.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That is not the Son from Mortis trilogy, but a (admittedly similar looking) new Dark-side Imperial character called [the Inquisitor.](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Inquisitor)

From the wiki:

> The Inquisitor was a male Pau'an agent of the Galactic Empire who hunted and eliminated Jedi who had survived the destruction of the Jedi Order. The Inquisitor received his orders from Darth Vader, who tasked him with converting or destroying Force-sensitive children, as well as Jedi who could train them, before they could become a threat to the Empire. To accomplish his tasks, the Inquisitor was trained in the ways of the dark side of the Force and studied the records of the Jedi Temple, giving him insight into the Jedi and their fighting style. As a result, he was a deadly foe for any surviving Jedi.

Comment: Where is he on the poster? I can't see...

Answer (score 13):

The character you're referring to is "The Inquisitor". He has similar facial markings to "The Son" but despite their outward similarity, they aren't the same character nor are they even from the same race.

**[The Son](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Son):**
[image]

**[The Inquisitor](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Inquisitor):**
[image]

Comment: Perhaps it shows the Empire is in need of better skin care products and more extensive fashion design other than "basic high collar black" for its higher rank officers. And what happens when those face tattoos go out of style?

Comment: @Thaddeus - Yes. What if he decided he wanted to get a job in face-to-face sales?

Comment: @Thaddeus Is the Son part of the Empire? I'm not familiar with the character, but judging by what I read in Wookieepedia, it's an extradimensional creature unrelated to the Empire or the Sith...