# Hidden meaning for the similarity between these two characters?

Tags: star-wars

Is there a symbolic, thematic, or narrative reason for the similarity between the Son and the Inquisitor?

[image]

Comment: wiki says it's kinda sort intentional / unintentional - http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Son#cite_note-Insider_153-10

Comment: Related, not dupe; https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/73007/why-is-the-son-on-the-star-wars-rebels-poster